# TypeError: posts is not iterable returning data from firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm new using react and firebase.
I try to get posts from firebase:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(false);
    let cancel;

    // get posts
    var postsRef = firebase.database().ref('/posts/');
    postsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        setPosts(prevPosts => {     
            var posts = snapshot.val();
            console.log(posts);

            return [...prevPosts,...posts]      
        });
    });

    setLoading(false);

}, [ pageNumber ]);
```

The problem is it gives me:

> TypeError: posts is not iterable on `return [...prevPosts,...posts]`

any ideas how to solve this? this will return data to a function that will parse data like this:

```
return (
    <>
      {posts.map((post, index) => {

        return <Post key={post.id} id={post.id} ref={ref} img={post.img} titulo={post.titulo} />

      })}
    </>
  )
```

Why I get this error? how can I parse my data correctly?
thanks!

Comment: What is the value of  `posts` when you `console.log` it? And can you add the code where you define the `setPosts` method? I expect it is created through `useState`?

Comment: `snapshot.forEach(doc => { ingredients.push(doc) })` You need to iterate using forEach and then pushes all values to array.. now you have all object as an array. in this case ingredietns is array of objects.

Comment: @mgarcia return an object like this: `Object
-M5GmoelPzWryNizVjww: {img: "img/", titulo: "title 1", user: "root"}
-M5GmsTDcbDYZuoYBVIt: {img: "img/", titulo: "title 2", user: "root"}
-M5GmxMZMzZe9p5uDuWe: {img: "img/", titulo: "title 3", user: "root"}
-M5GmyKDbbtxR8Dw3-J2: {img: "img/", titulo: "title 4", user: "root"}
-M5GmzHjK1PQJ2ulrCTi: {img: "img/", titulo: "title 5", user: "root"}
-M5Gn2Rsv_OrwL1GkbVG: {img: "img/", titulo: "title 6", user: "user"}
-M5Gn39y9JDishOdxwi4: {img: "img/", titulo: "title 7", user: "user"}
__proto__: Object`

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I will try :) thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `post` variable is an object like:

```
{
    "-M5GmoelPzWryNizVjww": { img: "img/", titulo: "title 1", user: "root" },
    "-M5GmsTDcbDYZuoYBVIt": { img: "img/", titulo: "title 2", user: "root" },
    "-M5GmxMZMzZe9p5uDuWe": { img: "img/", titulo: "title 3", user: "root" },
    "-M5GmyKDbbtxR8Dw3-J2": { img: "img/", titulo: "title 4", user: "root" },
    "-M5GmzHjK1PQJ2ulrCTi": { img: "img/", titulo: "title 5", user: "root" },
    "-M5Gn2Rsv_OrwL1GkbVG": { img: "img/", titulo: "title 6", user: "user" },
    "-M5Gn39y9JDishOdxwi4": { img: "img/", titulo: "title 7", user: "user" }
}
```

You should transform it previously to an array so that you can concatenate it to your previous list of posts. To do so, and using the key of the object as an id, you can use:

```
return [...prevPosts, ...Object.keys(posts).map(key => ({
    id: key,
    ...posts[key]
}))];
```